# Objective C JSON parsing not working

Tags: objective-c, json

Let me try my best to explain this:

```
    NSString *iIngreients = @"[1,2,3];
```

Now I am trying to load an NSArray with the values 1, 2, and 3.

So I,

```
    NSError *error4
    NSData = *jsonIngredients = [iIngredients dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *theIngredientsGroup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonIngredients          options:0 error:&error4];
```

So this appears to work when I step through, but when I pass it to another array through a function it passes as nil.

Any one have any ideas why this is happening?
thanks

Comment: And what does `error4` report???

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted more code, but this works just fine:

```
NSString* fakeJSON = @"[1,2,3]";
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* jsonIngredients = [fakeJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray* ingredientsList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonIngredients
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", ingredientsList); // prints the 1,2,3 array
```

Comment: It prints: ( 1, 2, 3) . are the () suppose to be there?

Comment: Yes, it means you're printing an NSArray.